# Tests not being found in a Django project

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I'm trying to run tests in a Django project using python migrate.py test, but it doesn't seem to pick up anything.

I currently have the following structure:

```
Project dir
|
- MyProject
- myApp
- tests
  |
  - __init.py__ 
  - test_forms.py
  - test_integration.py
  - test_models.py
  - test_views.py
```

Previously I had the tests folder as a sub folder under myAPp, but the same problem arises, namely that no tests are found:

```
python manage.py test --debug-mode
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

There's really very little in the test files at the moment - I just want to get them to run to start with! This is an example:

```
import unittest

class TestGeneric(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skip('Skipping default nothing test for test_views')
    def test_bugger_all(self):
        self.fail("Shouldn't get here")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

If I run this with python -m test_views.py, then it works just fine, but from the project root, python manage.py test picks up nothing at all. The tests are named as test_*, as are the .py files.

If it's relevant, I'm running in a virtualenv.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The test runner won't discover your tests if they're not directly accessible via the `tests` namespace. Since you have a package, with tests modules within that package, Django won't discover them.

You need to import the files within your `tests/__init__.py`.

Comment: Going to answer my own question now, as while looking to setup as Daniel suggested (even though as I understood it a blank __init__.py should leave everything available) - I realised I didn't have <underscore>init<underscore>.py", I had "<underscore>init.py<underscore>" ... which of course was the problem! Score one for user stupidity.